# using the OR function in Excel

Tags: function, excel-formula

I am just trying to use the `OR` function in Excel for analyzing some string variables.  Instead of using a character count to verify whether someone anwered correctly, I would like to use the or function to accept more than one answer as correct.

For instance, `return 1 if cell = "she was always there" or "she was there always"`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with "TRUE" or "FALSE" returns, then you don't need the IF function.  Just:

```
=OR(A1="she was always there",A1="she was there always")
```

I found that by Googling "EXCEL OR FUNCTION"

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/or-function-HP010062403.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(OR(A1="this",A1="that"),1,0)
```

IF takes three values:

1. The logical test
2. The value if true
3. The value if false

Each value can take other functions as it's argument. In this case, we use an OR function as the logical test. The OR can take any number of arguments (I'm sure there is a limit but I've never seen it). Each OR argument takes the form of a logical test and if any of the logical tests are TRUE, then the result of the OR is TRUE.

As a side note, you can nest many functions to create complex tests. But the nesting limit seems to be set at 7. Though there are tricks you can use to get around this, it makes reading the function later very difficult.

Comment: You should detail more the way it's working, for instance `OR` can receive more than 2 arguments.